# @Autowired get null value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In Login class @Autowired is not null but when I try to use postman call Logout class @Autowired get null. I copy code from Login to Logout class just change variable name all code is same pattern I don't know what happening

```
package xxx.api.login
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import xxx.api.domain.logout.LoginRequest;
import xxx.api.domain.logout.LoginResponse;
import xxx.converter.FieldValidation;
import xxx.dto.log.MessageLog;
import xxx.logging.LogFactory;

@Component
public class LoginClient {

    @Autowired
    FieldValidation fieldValidation;

    public LoginResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final String url = "http://localhost:xxx/xxx/login";
        LoginResponse responseObject = null;
        try {
            String requestData = mapper.writeValueAsString(loginRequest);
            responseObject = login(url, requestData);
            fieldValidation.validateResponse(responseObject, "login"); 
// 'fieldValidation' not null
```

This is my Login class. Return result as I expect.

```
package xxx.api.logout;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import xxx.api.domain.logout.LogoutRequest;
import xxx.api.domain.logout.LogoutResponse;
import xxx.converter.FieldValidation;
import xxx.dto.log.MessageLog;
import xxx.logging.LogFactory;

@Component
public class LogoutClient {

    @Autowired
    FieldValidation fieldValidation;

    public LogoutResponse logout(LogoutRequest logoutRequest) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final String url = "http://localhost:xxx/xxx/logout";
        LogoutResponse responseObject = null;
        try {
            String requestData = mapper.writeValueAsString(logoutRequest);
            responseObject = logout(url, requestData);
            fieldValidation.validateResponse(responseObject, "logout"); 
// 'fieldValidation' is null then throws nullPointerException
```

This is my Logout class

```
package xxx.api.logout;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import xxx.api.domain.logout.LogoutRequest;
import xxx.api.domain.logout.LogoutResponse;
import xxx.dto.log.MessageLog;
import xxx.exception.common.ErrorException;
import xxx.api.logout.LogoutClient;
import xxx.converter.FieldValidation;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/xxx")
public class LogoutServer {

    @Autowired
    FieldValidation fieldValidation;

    @Autowired
    WSLogFactory wsLog;

    @PostMapping(value = "/logout", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(@RequestHeader(value = "requestId") String requestId,
            @RequestBody(required = true) LogoutRequest logoutRequest) throws ErrorException, Exception {
        writeLogRequest(logoutRequest, logoutRequest.getClientIP(), "Request", "/xxx/logout");
        fieldValidation.validateRequest(logoutRequest, "logout");
        try {
            LogoutClient logoutClient = new LogoutClient();
            LogoutResponse response = logoutClient.logout(logoutRequest);
            return new ResponseEntity<LogoutResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

This is Logout Controller

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${layout.properties_file}")
public class FieldValidation {
      // do somethings
}
```

This is my FieldValidation class.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1550490230074,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/umm/logout"
}
```

This is return when I call my Logout class.

This is my project structure

```
xxx.api.login <<< LoginClient.java
xxx.api.logout <<< LogoutClient.java
xxx.converter <<< FieldValidation.java
```

This is my main program

```
package xxx;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I try to replace @Component to @Configuration but still doesn't works.

I don't need 'fieldValidation' in Logout class or another class be a null value.

```
package xxx.converter;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.BigDecimalValidator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import xxx.exception.common.ErrorException;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${layout.properties_file}")
public class FieldValidation {
public void validateObject(Object objResponse, String config) throws Exception {
    try {
        List<Configuration> confs = objectMapper.readValue(config,
                objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Configuration.class));
        for (int i = 0; i < confs.size(); i++) {
            Configuration configuration = confs.get(i);
            Object objValue = getValue(configuration.getFieldName(), objResponse);

            Validation validation = new Validation();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(validation, configuration);
            isValid(objValue, validation);

            if (configuration.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("object")) {
                List<Validation> validations = configuration.getValidation();
                Class<?> act = Class.forName(configuration.getClassName());
                Object objectConfig = act.cast(objValue);
                validateObject(objectConfig, validations);

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This is full import of FieldValidation class and replace @Configuration and I get this error.

configuration.getFieldName() << error The method is undefined for type Configuration

configuration.getType() << error The method is undefined for type Configuration

configuration.getValidation() << error The method is undefined for type Configuration

configuration.getClassName() << error The method is undefined for type Configuration

Comment: Don't autowire fields. Autowire constructor parameters. Easier to test.

Comment: Check paths for component scan.

Comment: @mate00 How ???

Comment: give more details on your project structure and environment. are you using spring-boot ? in which packages are those classes ?

Comment: Could you show imports?

Comment: https://springframework.guru/spring-component-scan/

Comment: @NikolayRusev Yes, I'm using spring-boot

Comment: in which package is the main spring boot application class?

Comment: @Tom okay its added.

Comment: @NikolayRusev xxx package

Comment: also need main application class and will be easy if you share project somewhere. Looks like small issue because everything looks okay

Comment: @NikolayRusev I added main program for u already. But I can't share my project to you.

Comment: can't see where can be the problem :) no sense to be null in one class and not null in the other if both classes are in same package

Comment: @NikolayRusev Yes, that is the point !!! Its not suppose to be null !!!

Comment: Because you used a full qualified annotation for `Configuration`  `@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration` I wanted to ask if you use other `@Configuration` in your `FieldValidation` class? Could you please show the `package` and `import` statements for each class declaration?

Comment: @thehandofNOD I try to replace Configuration but get some error in code.

Comment: Which error? Please update your question with the complete code and all `import` statements of all classes (in the same code section for each class ;-) ).

Comment: Can you please show the relevant code where LogoutClient is used (like the RestController for your endpoint etc.)?

Comment: @thehandofNOD i edited my code already

Comment: @dunni Okay you got this.

Comment: ok. now I see. At first replace your `@Configuration` Annotation with `@Component` in your `FieldValidation` class. Second. Also add the `package` statements in your code (in `LoginClient` and `LogoutClient`). What build tool do you use? Maven? Gradle? Also try to change the loglevel from spring to the TRACE oder DEBUG level to see what happens at startup of your application.

Comment: Well, `LogoutClient logoutClient = new LogoutClient();` won't work, since it's not a Spring Bean. And i'm pretty sure that you didn't do this with the LoginClient. You have to inject LogoutClient in the rest controller as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Comment: @dunni Autowired LogoutClient is work !!! Thanks a lot everyone.